# Rational Application Developer / Websphere polluting home directory

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, websphere, ibm-rad

When I installed RAD with Websphere 7.0, I got a slew of folders created in my home directory:

```
%USERPROFILE%\IBM
%USERPROFILE%\Logs
%USERPROFILE%\PMT
%USERPROFILE%\updilogs
%USERPROFILE%\waslogs
%USERPROFILE%\web2feplogs
```

I am using Windows 7, so I actually use my home directory for various things, and hate that I have all these folders polluting my home directory (more than half of which are sitting empty).

Which of these can I delete? If RAD/Websphere need the directories, is there any way I can configure RAD/Websphere to have them to where they're *supposed* to be (that is, under %USERPORFILE%\AppData)?

(And I have hidden files/folders showing for work-related reasons, so I can't just hide them)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so:

1. The `%USERPROFILE%\IBM` directory is the default directory for RAD to create new workspaces in. I am guessing that this directory was created when you first invoked RAD and it asked you where you would like a workspace created. Check the contents of that directory. If it only contains RAD workspaces, you can delete it (or move the individual workspace directories elsewhere).
2. I am not aware of a `%USERPROFILE%\Logs` directory created by wither RAD or WebSphere. Can you list some of the directory's contents?
3. The `%USERPROFILE%\PMT` directory wouldn't have been created by WebSphere or RAD. `PMT` stands for *Profile Management Tool* - a GUI that WebSphere provides for managing WebSphere profiles. Can you list some of the directory's contents?
4. `%USERPROFILE%\updilogs` are logs created by the installer of the WebSphere Update Installer (read that again). You cannot override it. You can delete this directory.
5. `%USERPROFILE%\waslogs` are logs created by the installer of WAS itself. You cannot override it. You can delete this directory.
6. `%USERPROFILE%\web2feplogs` are logs created by the installer of the WAS Web 2.0 Feature Pack. You cannot override it. You can delete this directory.

**EDIT** as per comment: The `PMT\workspace` directory seems to be of the format of an Eclipse workspace. I suspect this one was created when you (or a program that you ran) fired up the Profile Management Tool in GUI mode. As far as I know, this directory can be deleted but it will resurface next time you run PMT in GUI mode.

Comment: `Logs` is empty (it's possible it was created by something else and I misattributed). `PMT` contains one directory, `workspace`; that directory contains `.metadata` and `configuration`; `configuration` contains three folders: `org.eclipse.core.runtime`, `org.eclipse.osgi`, `and org.eclipse.update`. Those three folders have some files within them, but fairly sparse, and some of them looking like Lock files of some sort.